# Getting the ID in of an ASP drop down list from client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side

What I'm trying to do is get one of my drop down list to change its contents whenever the selected item in another one cahnges.  I have this code in my aspx file:

```
function ModifyDDLItems(id1, id2) 
{
    var ddlcontrolShown = document.getElementById(id1);
    var ddlcontrolHidden = document.getElementById(id2);

    if (ddlcontrolShown.options[ddlcontrolShown.selectedIndex].value == "DD1") 
    {
        //Get number of items of hidden ddl
        var length = ddlcontrolHidden.options.length;

        //Clear items of shown ddl
        ddlcontrolShown.options.length = 0;

        //Add itmems of hidden ddl to shown ddl
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        {
            ddlcontrolShown.options.add
            var newoption = document.createElement("option")
            newoption.text = ddlcontrolHidden.options[i].text;
            newoption.value = ddlcontrolHidden.options[i].text.value;
        }         
    }   
}
```

Now, i give it the front end ID's thru this:

```
protected void SetDD1ConfItems(GridViewRow gvRow, DataSet BaseConfItems)
{
    DataView dvConfType = new DataView(BaseConfItems.Tables[0]);
    DataSet dsTemp = BaseConfItems.Clone();

    DropDownList ddlConfType2 = (DropDownList)form1.FindControl("ddlConfType2");
    DropDownList ddlBA = (DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("ddlBA");
    DropDownList ddlConfType = (DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("ddlConfType");

    dvConfType.RowFilter = "ref_code = 'FAX' or ref_code = 'EEX' or ref_code = 'EPD'";

    dsTemp.Tables.Clear();
    dsTemp.Tables.Add(dvConfType.ToTable());

    ddlConfType2.DataSource = dsTemp;
    ddlConfType2.DataBind();
    //ddlBA.Attributes["onchange"] = "function GetDDLD(" + ddlConfType.ClientID + ", " + ddlConfType2.ClientID + ") {ModifyDDLItems(id1, id2);}";
    ddlBA.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ModifyDDLItems('" + ddlConfType.ClientID + "', '" + ddlConfType2.ClientID + "')");
}
```

When I run it, VS keeps on telling me that id1 and id2 are both null, it seems the id's aren't passed to the client properly.

Comment: Are you sure that ddlConfType and ddlConfType2 are your intended controles? Put a breakpoint right there (SetDD1ConfItems function) to findout if they are the correct controls

Comment: yes Kiarash they are the ones I want.  ddlConfTYpe2  holds the content that would be copied to ddlconfType.  Thx for the response

Answer (score 0):

I think you have code wrongly, the first mistake i found at a glance is,

You cannot find the controls inside gridview by using

```
gvRow.FindControl("ddlBA");
```

There may be multiple rows in GridView, so you have to find your controls in each Row as all of them will have different ClientIDs. First to try to replace the below code

```
gvRow.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("ControlID");
```

ALso, it should be written in the some kind of **loop** in order to find the RowIndex value of the Grid.

Describe your exact requirement in brief. So, that i can help you in writing the proper code.

Comment: Hi. I appreciate the help. Just to let you know, gv is already a gridview row.  I apologize for the name it has, it's already pre existing code :(